# 1st Draft of Dune with a different plot

Tags: dune, episode-identification

I remember reading about a decade ago a hard back book that included an earlier draft of Dune by Herbert which featured much less of the political and religious aspects associated with the work and focused mostly on ecological exploration and involved the Duke surviving. Does anyone know the name of this, I've been trying to search but just get links to other books in the series or articles on the series in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would it be "The Road to Dune"?  I've had it for a while, haven't taken the time to read it, but it is about the right age (copyright 2005) and one of the sections is "Spice Planet The Alternative Dune Novel".